# What is the difference between Jdeps & Jdeprscan?

Tags: java, java-9, jdeps, jdeprscan

In Java 9 a new tool jdeprscan has been introduced, which is quite similar to the existing jdeps tool.

As per my understanding jdeprscan's primary motive is to harness the usage of 'for-removal' & 'release' attributes of the Deprecated annotation.

Is there any other scenario or usage for this tool, which cannot be performed using JDeps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your understanding in terms of what `jdeprscan` does is correct. The [`jdeprscan` tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeprscan.htm#JSWOR-GUID-2B7588B0-92DB-4A88-88D4-24D183660A62) is precisely meant for

> static analysis scanning a JAR file or some other aggregation of class files ***for uses of deprecated API elements***.

It's also important to note that

> The deprecated APIs identified by the `jdeprscan` tool are *only those
>   that are defined by Java SE*. Deprecated APIs defined by third-party
>   libraries aren’t reported.

---

Though, IMO you shall also understand that there is no comparison of the tool with `jdeps`, which on the other hand is not meant to identify deprecated APIs but instead analyze the dependencies of a class/package.

In short, they are exclusive in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk.jdeps-summary.html), [jdeprscan](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeprscan.htm#JSWOR-GUID-2B7588B0-92DB-4A88-88D4-24D183660A62) only exists as a command line tool, and does not provide any direct API.

Comment: sample `Optional<ToolProvider> javac = ToolProvider.findFirst("jdeps");
        int javacRun = javac.get().run(
                System.out,
                System.err,
                "--help"
        );` that would not run if we replace jdeps with jdeprscan.